# Baby Rudin Theorem 3.31 - help with second part of proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have a question on the second part of the proof where $n \geq m$.

I understand that when $n \rightarrow \infty$, $s_m \leq \lim \inf t_n$.

However, when $m \rightarrow \infty$, it states that $e \leq \lim \inf t_n$.

This should not be true since $$t_n = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}(1 - \frac{1}{n}) + \frac{1}{3!}(1 - \frac{1}{n})(1 - \frac{2}{n}) + ... + \frac{1}{n!}(1 - \frac{1}{n})(1 - \frac{2}{n}) ... (1 - \frac{n - 1}{n})$$ and $$s_m = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{1}{m!}$$.

So when both n and m converges to infinity, shouldn't $\lim \inf t_n \leq \lim \inf s_m = e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the second expression for $t_n$ contains terms with $m$. The estimate with the $\liminf$ follows readily. Also, it seems like you missed the order in which $m,n \to \infty$.

To see that the second expression for $t_n$ is correct, look at the expression you wrote, and instead of writing all the $n$ terms, instead write only $m\leq n$ terms. Clearly $\leq$ will hold since all these terms are non-negative.

Comment: I understand that $$s_m = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{1}{m!}$$ and $$s_n = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{1}{m!} + ... + \frac{1}{n!}$$ since $m \leq n$. However, if both $n$ and $m$ converges to infinity, will both $s_n$ and $s_m$ be the same? since $s_n = s_m = s_{\infty}$?

Comment: After some thought, i finally understand the last part of the proof. Thank you for your help.